# How to continue providing method on array until it's become equal to other array

Tags: java, arrays, int, equals

I have int1[k] array with values equal to it's indexes `{0,1,2,3...}`.

I also have a method1 that takes that array and returns another int2[k] with values shuffled in such manner:

initial deck:       `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

shuffled deck:      `4 0 5 1 6 2 7 3`

And finally I have a method2 that accept any int[k] array and counts shuffles of method1 on it required to get it back to original state:

```
Shuffles    Deck Order  
    0       0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7  
    1       4, 0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3  
    2       6, 4, 2, 0, 7, 5, 3, 1  
    3       7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0  
    4       3, 7, 2, 6, 1, 5, 0, 4   
    5       1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 2, 4, 6  
    6       0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

6 times here.

At that final method I want to run `do{}while()` cycle with condition "until new array is not equal to original itself" and despite System.out.printing shows that array is changing on each iteration (and become equal to original state) equality in condition never becomes true.

```java
public class PerfectShuffle {
private int[] deck;
public PerfectShuffle(int size) {
        this.deck = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this.deck[i] = i;
        }
    }

public int[] method1(int[] input) {
        int[] newDeck = new int[input.length];
        int[] input1 = new int[input.length/2];
        int[] input2 = new int[input.length/2];
        System.arraycopy(input, 0, input1, 0, input.length/2);
        System.arraycopy(input, input.length/2 - 1, input2, 0, input.length/2);
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length/2; i++){
            newDeck[i*2 + 1] = input1[i];
            newDeck[i*2] = input2[i];
        }
        return newDeck;
    }

 public int method2() {
        int[] tempDeck = this.deck;
        int count = 0;
        do {
            tempDeck = this.method1(tempDeck);
            count++;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempDeck));
        } while (!Arrays.equals(tempDeck, this.deck));
        return count;
    }
}
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PerfectShuffle s = new PerfectShuffle(52);
        System.out.println( s.method2() );
    }
}
```

I'm expecting a number but insted it simply "thinks" for a long time.

Comment: What does line `tempDeck = this.inShuffle(tempDeck);` do?

Comment: Sorry. My poor edition of original program. Will edit in a minute.

Comment: @FullStackly is your programming printing anything to the console?

Comment: i printed both tempDeck and deck. -> ```[7, 15, 23, 31, 39, 47, 4, 12, 20, 28, 36, 44, 1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 49, 6, 14, 22, 30, 38, 46, 3, 11, 19, 27, 35, 43, 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 5, 13, 21, 29, 37, 45, 2, 10, 18, 26, 34, 42, 50, 7]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51]``` your shuffled deck has two times zero and goes up to 50 while the original goes from 0 to 51

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong: `System.arraycopy(input, input.length/2 - 1, input2, 0, input.length/2);` . It has an off-by-one error.

The source array start index should be `input.length/2`.

Comment: I think this is the bug, since the deck goes from 0 to 51 and the shuffled one goes from 0 to 50 while having the int 0 two times

Comment: Wow. Youre advice helped to get the answer. It was a very embarrasing mistake of mine. I'm an early learner. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I changed input.length/2 - 1 to input.length/2 and I got correct answer 52.